# ES6 import/export with Node command line tool

Tags: node.js, npm, babeljs

I'm writing a CLI with Node and ES6. I opted to use Babel's require hook and my entry file looks like this (`index.js`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
require('babel-core/register');
require('babel-polyfill');
require('./lib');
```

and `package.json`'s command points to that file:

```
"bin": {
  "atlas": "./index.js"
},
```

Everything works perfectly when developing and I can run the script locally. Once I publish it on NPM and install it with `--global`, I get the following error regarding ES6's `import` statements:

```
~ atlas login
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/atlas-cli/lib/index.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import program from 'commander';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:528:28)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/atlas-cli/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/atlas-cli/index.js:10:1)
```

It looks like Babel isn't loading `.babelrc` due to symlinking or similar. If I run the command in the install directory (`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/atlas-cli`), the command works just fine.

Full code for the package is available [here](http://github.com/jorilallo/atlas-cli).

Comment: Your "full code" link isn't working.

Comment: @Frxstrem uups, forgot to hit publish. I'll check the link, didn't come across that one in my research

Comment: @Frxstrem Thanks, appears that the same solution worked for me